# Running VNC server on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 by creating new sessions

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, 18.04

I would like to create a VNC server that runs gnome-shell environment, the same as the default UI in the console, separate from the console session (so that the console cannot see anything).

I tried `vnc4server` and `tightvncserver`, neither worked. No matter how I configured `xstartup`, `gnome-session` just won't run. I did manage to run `Xfdm` and `gnome-panel` in the same way. When I try to connect to the VNC server I get only grey screen. However I can confirm that the vnc server worked because I can run programs in it by setting `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`.

Is there a way to get `ubuntu-desktop` running in a new X session, separate from the console session? Preferably on a VNC server?

Steps I created the vnc server:

1. Install a completely new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop.
2. Install `tightvncserver`.
3. Run `vncserver` to configure and kill it.
4. Change `~/.vnc/xstartup` and append:

   export STARTUP="/usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu --disable-acceleration-check"
   $STARTUP
5. Run `vncserver`.
6. Connect to the VNC server with any VNC client. Only grey screen is shown.
7. Configure `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` and run `gedit`. The VNC session sees an incomplete `gedit` window.

Comment: Do you insist on using VNC? With xpra it should be easier to get there.

Comment: If it's not VNC then I'd prefer a protocol that works over a slow Internet connection, and has clients on all operating systems - Android, Windows, etc. xpra seems to forward X connections which is not what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found the solution.

The Gnome session doesn't seem to work on VNC X servers, but an Xvfb will work.
The idea is to create an Xvfb for the session and use x11vnc for VNC:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x720x24
```

Then spawn GNOME environment:

```
DISPLAY=:1 gnome-shell --replace
```

Finally use `x11vnc` to create an VNC server for Xvfb:

```
x11vnc -display :1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in xstartup or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you unset the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS at the beginning of the `xstartup` script.

Here is a snip of mine that have gnome-session started properly. However, the only issue so far is that the color scheme of the terminal is not properly applied, but VNC runs fine :)

```
#!/bin/sh
MODE="GNOME"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
if [ -e "$HOME/.Xresources" ]
then
    xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
fi

if [ "GNOME" = "$MODE" ]
then
    if which gnome-session > /dev/null
    then
        gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
    else
        MODE=""
    fi
fi
```

Comment: `MODE="` should be `MODE=""` , UN-terminated quotes. syntax error.

Comment: which vnc server are you using ?  I tried your script with tightvnc and I can see only a screen without anything on it.

Comment: I am using [tigervnc-v1.9.0](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/releases).